# Spring Security pre authentication matcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` for my RESTful webservices. However, certain requests should be available for all users and should not require the additional header. For example:

```
/articles/**        requires header
/items/**           requires header
/cmd/**             does not require header
```

So, I tried using the following in my Spring security configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/cmd/**").anonymous().and()
      .addFilterBefore(securityFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(DEFAULT_USER_ROLE);
  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
  http.csrf().disable();
  super.configure(http);
}
```

But this does not seem to work as expected, because if I launch the following request:

```
GET /test-services/cmd/test
```

It still requires the header, since it throws the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/test-services] threw exception
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException: Authenticated-User header not found in request.
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is it possible to apply the filter only in specific cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of changing the filter chain I changed the context of all security-related API's, so for example now I have:

```
/api/secured/articles/**        requires header
/api/secured/items/**           requires header
/api/cmd/**                     does not require header
```

And now I applied the `DelegatingFilterProxy` only to the `/api/secured*` requests.

Answer (score 1):

if the number of protected URL patterns is small enough, you can register filter only for them, leaving `/cmd/**` out. Although it is not very nice solution.

Additional possible solution could be to write our filter that will exclude specific URLs from filtering and for others it just call original filter. Make something like [here](http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1024/).

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    if (matchExcludePatterns(url)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    // call your filter
}
```

Comment: I tried the second approach, but it doesn't seem to work, maybe because I have no idea how to call the filter. I tried writing: `new DelegatingFilterProxy().doFilter(request, response, chain);` But that doesn't seem to do the trick.